# AlarmManager problem?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm using AlarmManager in my app. I want to display the user a warning while alarm occurs.
I used an AlertDialog but it gives an error. How can I solve this problem?
And I want to put the warning sound and vibration. Any link or code.

```
public class AReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

 AlertDialog alertDialog;

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); // Error here: The constructor AlertDialog.Builder is undefined.
     alertDialog.setTitle("title");

     alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            return;
        } });

 }
}
```

Comment: @@realuser have you checked Answer?

Comment: @@realuser if you find this answer is right then right it so more helpful to other.

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can not used AlertDialog in `BroadcastReceiver`..

you call another Activity class in `BroadcastReciver` like below.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

And in this class you used Alert Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you the main idea of how to solve this problem.

- The BroadcastReceiver using in the AlarmManager is a static class with static context.
- AlertDialog should be executed in a non-static context instead of static context.

I have two solutions for this issue.

- Send an intent to other components with non-static context.

  example: https://github.com/yanfaxg/leaveme/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunny/leaveme/AlarmHelper.java#L93
- Use static callback. And set callback from a non-static method.

  example:
  https://github.com/sunnyleevip/leaveme/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunny/leaveme/common/AlarmHelper.java

So when you get the alarm event in an non-static context, you can use AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Late but maybe still useful for someone:

Correct the code like below:

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create(); // Now The constructor AlertDialog.Builder is defined.
```